# Closed form of this product?

Tags: closed-form, infinite-product

What is the closed form of this product: $$\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}(2^i)!, \forall k \geqslant 2 $$

The original question was turning a recursive formula into a closed form formula, I managed to get the above product but I don't know how to write it in closed form.

Comment: you wrote a sum

Comment: Ah thank you for pointing the typo out, fixed it!

Comment: Not much help, but http://oeis.org/A261125

Comment: *Hint*: Using the Stirling formula and $k\geq 1$ one gets $\prod\limits_{i=1}^k (2^i)!=2^{(k-1)2^{k+1}+\frac{k(k+1)}{4}+2}e^{1+k-2^{k+1}} \prod\limits_{i=1}^k \prod\limits_{v=1}^{2^i-1}\frac{e}{(1+\frac{1}{v})^{v+\frac{1}{2}}}$. For the term $\prod\limits_{i=1}^k \prod\limits_{v=1}^{2^i-1}\frac{e}{(1+\frac{1}{v})^{v+\frac{1}{2}}}$ you can try to get an estimation.